# Bind a formula to a TextBox

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding

I'm doing a little program that needs to calculate the thickness of a book using its page count.

Please note that I'm almost completely new to programing. And this is my first time on ths website.

Here's the XAML.

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="25 5 0 10">
    <Slider Maximum="800" TickPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="1" 
           IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" DockPanel.Dock="Right" x:Name="slNumPages" 
           Margin="0" LargeChange="16" SmallChange="2" Value="200" Minimum="16" 
           BorderThickness="0" />

    <WrapPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=slNumPages, Path=Value, 
                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="40" />
        <TextBlock Text="Approx. thickness: " />
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbApproxThickness" Text="..."/>
    </WrapPanel>
```

How can I bind the TextBlock `tbApproxThickness` to a formula where the value of slider `slNumPages` gets multiplied by constant 0.0252?

Comment: you may perhaps need a converter here, simple binding does not allow the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Margin="25 5 0 10"
            xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <l:ApproxThicknessConverter x:Key="ApproxThicknessConverter" />
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Slider Maximum="800"
            TickPlacement="BottomRight"
            TickFrequency="1"
            IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
            DockPanel.Dock="Right"
            x:Name="slNumPages"
            Margin="0"
            LargeChange="16"
            SmallChange="2"
            Value="200"
            Minimum="16"
            BorderThickness="0" />

    <WrapPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=slNumPages, Path=Value, 
            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 Width="40" />
        <TextBlock Text="Approx. thickness: " />
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbApproxThickness"
                   Text="{Binding Value,ElementName=slNumPages,Converter={StaticResource ApproxThicknessConverter}}" />
    </WrapPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

following are the changed for the same

```
<l:ApproxThicknessConverter x:Key="ApproxThicknessConverter" />

Text="{Binding Value,ElementName=slNumPages,Converter={StaticResource ApproxThicknessConverter}}"
```

converter class

```
namespace CSharpWPF
{
    class ApproxThicknessConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (double)value * 0.0252;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to refer to the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN to understand this answer. One simple solution would be to data bind a `double` property to the `Slider.Value` property and then reference this property in a formula property that does the calculation. Try something like this:

```
public double SliderValue
{
    get { return sliderValue; }
    set 
    { 
        sliderValue = value; 
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SliderValue"); // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged
        FormulaValue = sliderValue * 0.0252;
    }
}

public double FormulaValue { get; set; } // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged
```

...

```
<Slider Maximum="800" TickPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="1" 
       IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" DockPanel.Dock="Right" x:Name="slNumPages" 
       Margin="0" LargeChange="16" SmallChange="2" Value="{Binding SliderValue}" 
       Minimum="16" BorderThickness="0" />

<WrapPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=slNumPages, Path=Value, 
            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="40" />
    <TextBlock Text="Approx. thickness: " />
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbApproxThickness" Text="{Binding FormulaValue}" />
</WrapPanel>
```

Please bear in mind that you will need to implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) on these properties to make this work. You will also need to set the `DataContext` of the `Window` properly. Having done that, each time the `Slider` is moved, the property will automatically update the `FormulaValue`.